# Condensed ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am an experienced engineer and would like to hear recommendations about good and **condensed** books on ASP.NET MVC, that does not deal with basics. I don't need to be introduced to any patterns or to the web development fundamentals. On the other hand, the last web application I worked was running on asp.net web forms which was slightly before any AJAX framework was introduced. A book recommendation on the trendy/popular AJAX frameworks would also be very much appreciated.

Any suggestions, please

Thanks a lot

K.

NOTE: I, of course, had a look at book reviews on amazon, etc. What I am looking for is not recommendations from anyone but from people having similar profiles. Unfortunately, it is impossible to know the profile of the people who recommends books on bookstore web sites. I am essentially looking for advise from a fellow programmer who has many years of experience and possibly have had a similar requirement. I bought the books recommended and found them containing too much details that can be discovered anyways while working with it. Perhaps, what I am looking is a design description of the framework with brief explanations for key objects and components. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at these collection.

```
1. Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 (Expert's Voice in ASP.Net)
```

Great book, covers everything you need to learn to work with ASP.NET MVC, Highly recommended.

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118794753/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118794753)

```
2. Hands on with ASP.NET MVC 6.
```

This book covers all the tiny steps on using MVC at its best. With complete practical tutorials to illustrate the concepts, you will step by step build one End to End application which covers below mentioned techniques - Controllers, Views, Models, Forms and HTML helpers, Data annotation and Validation, Membership, Authorization, Security rather you will also learn how to bootstrap your design, then how to host the app in AZURE, Web API and Dependency Injection.